# command execution on MacOSx in golang

Tags: macos, go

I have a simple golang program to start an application in MacOSx.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)
func main() {
out1,err1 := exec.Command("/usr/bin/open ", " -a", "calcultor").Output()
log.Printf(" output is err  ", err1)
log.Printf(" output is err  ", out1)

}
```

I expect it to start application in calculator after execution but i receive following errors

> 2017/04/26 16:01:26  output is err%!(EXTRA *os.PathError=fork/exec
>   /usr/bin/open : no such file or directory) 2017/04/26 16:01:26  output
>   is out%!(EXTRA []uint8=[])

I am trying it on OSx 10.11.

Comment: You have a space after `open` and `calculator` is misspelled. The space before `-a` may also cause problems. You're also using `Printf()` wrong.

Comment: You are using fmt.Print**F**.

Comment: spaces between  after open  and before -a were causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a spelling mistake - "calcultor" should be "calculator".

Comment: even with correct spelling same output   =====  2017/04/26 17:45:47  output is err  %!(EXTRA *os.PathError=fork/exec /usr/bin/open : no such file or directory)
2017/04/26 17:45:47  output is out  %!(EXTRA []uint8=[])